# Creating links using link_to for hierarchical model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

Okay, so I am new to Rails and am creating a project management system with the framework. For a couple of my models, views, and controllers I used scaffolding and had no problems. For other parts, I coded all of the parts myself.

So as an overview of my project, at the root of it all you can have many projects. Within all of these projects you can create multiple to-do lists. Within each to-do list, you can have multiple tasks. This is what I meant by "hierarchical" in the title.

I just created my lists page, and when I go to the URL directly in my browser (ex: `http://localhost:3000/projects/3/lists/20/tasks/1`) the task is displayed correctly. However, I do not know how to format my link that is in one of my to-do list views (the tasks are usually shown below the to-do list but now I want them to show on their own view).

Here is the code I currently have:

```
<%= link_to "#{task.description}", project_list_tasks_url(@list.id,task.id) %>
```

I know that the `link_to "#{task.description}"` is correct because I tried using it with a static URL (Google or something), but `project_list_tasks_url(@list.id,task.id)` is where I'm having trouble.

Can anybody help me out? I can provide as much code as you'd like from my to-do list or task controllers and views.

Comment: As a note, since `#{x}` and `x` are almost always identical, it's probably better to just use `task.description` here as your first argument. What you're doing is the equivalent of "scare quotes" and serves no purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of tips to help make routing less confusing. It can be a bit unnerving to get used to.

**Routing Rule #1**

Always check the output of `rake routes` to be sure how to call your various routing methods. You might *think* you know how your routes will play out by looking at `routes.rb` but you won't *know* until you look at the compiled routes table.

In your case you're expecting a route with the format:

```
/projects/:project_id/lists/:list_id/tasks/:id
```

Be sure that's the case. If it is, your call should look like:

```
project_list_task_path(@project, @list, task)
```

Note that the arguments here are `:project_id`, `:list_id` and `:id`, so all three are required in this case. Any in brackets in the path specification can be ignored, like `:format` usually is.

**Routing Rule #2**

Use the `_path` methods unless you strictly require the full URL. They're shorter and the output is easier to read and debug. They also don't inadvertently flip the URL in the browser and cause session problems if you don't properly differentiate between `www.mysite.com` and `site.com`.

**Routing Rule #3**

Don't forget there's a *huge* difference between `@project` and `@project.id` when it's supplied to a routing path method.

The router will always call the `to_param` method if it's available and this can be over-ridden in your model to produce pretty or friendly URLs. `id` is for your database and your database alone. `to_param` is for routing but you shouldn't be calling it manually unless you're doing something exceptionally irregular.

Comment: +1 your actual code is the same as mine, but you provide a great explanation.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for all of your help with this and the great explanation. I'll actually be able to go back and re-work a lot of my code with your tips. Thank you very very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

You generally should not nest resources [more than one level deep](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources), but putting that aside, the `link_to` format should be:

```
link_to task.description, project_list_task_path(@project, @list, task)
```

i.e. `project_link_tasks_url` should be `project_link_task_url`, and you have to pass the `@project` as the first argument (I'm assuming that your project is named `@project`). I've switched `_url` to `_path` so you can just pass the objects themselves as arguments rather than their ids.

See the [documentation on creating paths and URLs from objects](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects) for details.